# Отключить вывод ошибок в php 5.6?

Tags: php

Как отключить вывод ошибок в php 5.6, картинки, обрабатываемые некоторыми скриптами, не показываются, когда раньше мне хватало в .htaccess сделать данное:

```
php_flag log_errors Off
php_flag display_errors Off
php_flag display_startup_errors Off
```

Сейчас это уже не помогает и в php.ini я не совсем понял как отключить вывод ошибок совсем, но в index.php я прописал это `error_reporting( E_ERROR )`;

Comment: `error_reporting(0);`, `display_errors(false); ` ?

Answer (score 2):

Некоторым директивам в php.ini можно указывать значения на лету. Если у вас 1 входной файл (обычно php фреймворки так устроены), то можно использовать код для управления уровнем ошибок через [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Учитите, что во время выполнения скрипта эти директивы могут изменяться таким же образом.

Кстати если вы отдаете в клиенту картинку и в процессе произошла ошибка, то по логике вы и не должны увидеть картинку. Надо бы вернуть корректный HTTP статус и тип документа отличный от картинки.

PS. Если вы используете фреймворк, то почитайте мануал к нему, там точно должны быть указаны конфиги для управления обработки ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

В php.ini можно отключить вывод ошибок, назначив директиве `display_errors` значение Off или 0.

```
display_errors = Off
```

Для вступления изменений в силу следует выполнить перезагрузку сервера (apache в случае php_mod или php-fpm).

Обратите внимание, что директивы .htaccess работают только для Web-сервера Apache и только если включена директива `AllowOverride` глобально или на уровне виртуального хоста.

Comment: В /etc/apache2/apache2.conf AllowOverride сделал All, Web-сервер у меня Apache, также в php.ini поставил display_errors = Off, перезапустил, ничего, как проверить отключен ли вывод ошибок?

Comment: @StirolCraft посмотрите в отчете функции phpinfo(), в нем же уточните путь до php.ini, который использует PHP.

Comment: Да, в phpinfo() показано, что вывод ошибок отключен, но сегодня опять скрипт выдал ошибку и теперь снова картинки не отображаются, уже другой, и опять же раньше эти флаги в htaccess спасали...